# O array JSON não quer passar tudo para o meu listview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Está aqui o meu erro, quando executo a *app* no emulador, a *app* não recebe um único titulo do *array* JSON, não fecha a aplicação, o único erro que da é no logcat, era suposto estar a passar todos os titulos para a `listview`.

> 06-19 14:02:12.750    6497-6518/com.eu.agendamarinhagrande E/JSON
>   Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Sou novo em android portanto desculpem qualquer erro novato .

```
package com.eu.agendamarinhagrande;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.eu.agendamarinhagrande.JSONParser;
import com.eu.agendamarinhagrande.R;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> empresaList;


    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_empresas = "http://www.grifin.pt/projectoamg/Conexao.php";

    // JSON Node names


    private static final String TAG_TITULO = "Titulo";


    // products JSONArray
    String resultado = null;

    ListView lista;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Hashmap para el ListView
        empresaList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
        // Cargar los productos en el Background Thread

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }//fin onCreate


    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Antes de empezar el background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("A carregar eventos. Por favor espere...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * obteniendo todos los productos
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List params = new ArrayList();
            // getting JSON string from URL
          JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_empresas, "GET", params);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", url_all_empresas.toString());
            resultado = sb.toString();
            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG

                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products

                JSONArray arrayJson = new JSONArray(resultado);
                for (int i = 0; i<arrayJson.length();i++){



                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    JSONObject c = arrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
                    String Titulo = c.getString(TAG_TITULO);


                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap map = new HashMap();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_TITULO, Titulo);


                    empresaList.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            empresaList,
                            R.layout.single_post,
                            new String[]{
                                    TAG_TITULO

                            },
                            new int[]{
                                    R.id.single_post_tv_id

                            });
                    // updating listview
                    //setListAdapter(adapter);
                    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```